# support media query in IE7 and IE8

Tags: media

i use media query for responsive my site
but it doesn't support in IE<9
i download "matchmedia.js" and "css3-mediaqueries-js.js" code from github,BUT it doesn't work .
AM I missing something?
in addition i use this meta tag too,but it doesn't work.

Comment: IMO, if you are supporting responsive design in IE-7 and 8, you are still developing in a dinosaur world :)

Comment: Besides they have may not have any support in these browsers. [Check here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)

Comment: just block those browsers; they should be extinct by now.

Answer (score 0):

The polifill I used was adding styles for matched media queries as styles tags on the page. So rules were getting out of order.

For example such code

```
.smth { margin: 1em; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { .smth { margin: .5em; } }
.other { margin-top: 0; }
```

becomes reordered as

```
.smth { margin: 1em; }
.other { margin-top: 0; }
/* following line appears on the page */
.smth { margin: .5em; }
```

And in case of

```
<div class="smth other">...</div>
```

works incorrectly.

Check libraries you are using for having same problem.